# Java console output from another thread dropped

Tags: java, multithreading, console

I have a problem with the console output of one of my threads being dropped (in Java). The situation is as follows: I spawn a thread that listens (using a blocking method) for incoming messages. These messages are then asynchronously written to the console. Meanwhile, I read in the user input on the console via `System.console().readLine()`.

The problem is that the text is never written to the console at all. I mean, as the `readLine()` method is blocking, I would have expected the console at least to show the output that has been written to the console as soon as something is entered in the main thread.. Or am I missing the point here?

The relevant source is

```
// ...

// handle receiving messages
(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (executing) received(new String(subSocket.recv(0)));
    }
}).start();

// ...

String input;
try {
    while ((input = System.console().readLine()) != null && !input.equals(".")) {
        pubSocket.send(input.getBytes(), 0);
        Thread.yield();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) { }
finally {executing = false;}
```

And the received method is

```
public void received(String s) {
    System.console().format("(%s)", s);
    System.console().flush();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this? I mean, I tried to use a `BufferedReader` encapsulating the input stream in order to read it linewise and used `System.out.format()` along with it.. To the same effect - Nothing :(.

Cheers,
fxx

Comment: When you write to System.out you're not writing to the stream represented by the console, you're writing to the standard output and the System.console object represents the standard input, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

- Implement a thread to read from input and store it in synchronized map/vector/list etc..
- Another thread is listening on that collection, which will then process the message.

I think this should help in some way... Main thing is, don't run the loop on system input. Give it a try.

Comment: Thx for the help.. I tried it using a BlockingQueue but it didn't work, what drove me crazy. Then I turned to some other stuff and when I came back I realized that I did not initialize the executing flag properly, stupid me!! I guess it was just one of these days.. :(. With the executing flag set, it works like expected - you actually do not need to share some queue or other stuff between threads. But thanks again anyway..

Comment: @fxx: If you get a chance, could you update your code to contain the solution, or answer the question yourself? Thanks! :)